# Converting PHP Associative array to JSON object - spaces in value results in malformed JSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I build up an array in PHP and convert it to JSON which I then handle with an onclick event and send to another file via AJAX.

The problem is that some of the values in the php array have spaces in them. This seems to be breaking the JSON object meaning my AJAX call is failing.

Here's a snippet of code to try and elaborate:

```
//PHP Array looks like this:

            Array
            (
                [card_id] => 1
                [img_id] => 11
                [card_name] => Layout1retro_original
                [card_qty] => 1
                [img_thumb] => albums/160915_E165/thumbs/011_cover-lp-cd_originalDPP_Polaroid.jpg
                [img_hires] => 
                [img_full] => albums/160915_E165/images/011_cover-lp-cd_originalDPP_Polaroid.jpg
                [media] => retro
                [finish] => Perl290
                [size] => original
                [backing] => 
                [can_crop] => 
                [needs_to_be_cropped] => 1
                [been_cropped] => 
                [aspect_ratio] => 0
                [offer_CMF] => 
                [retro-name] => A value
            )
```

The problem `key => val` pair is the `retro-name`. The JSON is breaking where the space is between `A` and `value`.

I use `json_encode` to convert the array to a JSON object to pass with Javascript: `stripslashes(json_encode($array))`.

Then I add it to an html element as a `data attribute` so I can grab it with the `onclick` event.

Here's where it is breaking in the data attribute: `[removed excess code for clarity...] "retro-name":"A" value"}`

Notice it has added a closing `"` after `A`. This breaks the rest of the JSON object so my AJAX call fails.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your data attribute in quotation marks?

Comment: You could try using rawurlencode to encode it yourself.

Comment: @JosiahKeller yea it is. This is tested and works a treat when there's not a space in any of the values.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: @EliasNicolas I think I've explained the problem pretty clearly. The space in the key / value pair in the PHP array is breaking the JSON object like so: `"retro-name":"A" value"`

Comment: You provided examples, things here and there. But not something to answer. You have an array. You use `json_encode`, have you tried without `stripslashes`?

Comment: @EliasNicolas. Yes. I have.

Comment: Please provide accurate original data and a minimal code example, not some `print_r()` representation of the data or loosely described procedures, in which we are supposed to tie the whole thing together into workable code. From the looks of it, there's something fishy with the data, so give us an accurate sample of the data **before any** encoding. If I were to take a guess though, it's `stripslashes()` that is removing a slash in front of the escaped `"` after `A` in `A" value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best guess is because the JSON is rendered in a data attribute enclosed in double-quotes, as is common in HTML. Instead of double-quotes, please try single-quotes. PHP outputs JSON with double-quotes.

If this does not work, please can you update your question with an example of how the data-attribute is rendered with the JSON.

Comment: tried with single and double quotes,. This is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: Has this been copied from web inspector or from HTML view source?

Comment: copied from HTML view source - why? The raw html shows the the quotes as html entities (`&quot;`) which makes readability a bit difficult.

Comment: You need to wrap the attribute in single quotes like data-card='' for this to work. I can see this isn't the case from your examples. If your data contains a single quote, you will need to escape those to HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to take a guess, it's `stripslashes()` that is removing a slash in front of the (presumed) escaped `"` after `A` in `A" value`. I'm almost certain there's a `\` in front of the `"` in the original data, that you are not showing us verbatim.

Comment: Please see update. I don't think it is `stripslashes` causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

Just put the `card_id` in the card div

```
<div class="print-wrap has-size" data-card_id="<?=$array['card_id'];?>">
```

and then pass the card data into a variable in JS

```
<script>var card_data['<?=$array["card_id"]?>'] = <?=json_encode($array);?>;</script>
```

Then you have a relation to your data and the div.